# Flatten cylindrical image using lens

Tags: optics

I want to do something like this:
[image]

but I have 3 questions that need to be answered:

1. Is it possible to make this kind of lens?
2. If it is possible, what are the equations/measurements needed to make it?
3. Are there another alternative to make cylindrical image flat?

Additional note: Please no "image processing" or programming to flatten the image because I need to take a very high and precise image of the surface and I want to prevent any kind of blur from the camera input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "cylindrical" ? And by the way, that's the Object, not the Image.  Further,  image processing to remove distortions will not cause blurring or defocus.

Comment: Not _quite_ what you want but [360 Optics](http://www.opto-engineering.com/products/360-optics-family) machine vision may be of interest. For industrial vision applications a line-scan camera is used while rotating the part.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Presumably by blurring OP means due to the difference in distance from the lens. Closing the aperture of the camera can improve the depth of field and reduce blurring. OP needs to define "very high and precise" to get an optimal solution, however. It isn't clear from those words alone that digital post-processing will be insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, but it is going to be very expensive.
2. A mirror lense could also work the same way as a lense. Ive also done this digitally with one camera and 3 flat mirrors to read cylindrical labels.

   Probably also cylindrical line cameras exist, and you can also sweep a straight one (think table scanner in arc. This is 2-3 magnitudes cheaper than a lense.

   A digital solution with 3 or 4 cameras is prolbably  2-3 magnitudes cheaper than a custom lense and as good quality.

Your going to get problems with lighting your target if you use a very wide angle reader.